# Python - Find descendants and ancestors from the unsorted hierarchy file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a unsorted parent-child hierarchy file (tab delimited) in the following format:

```
City1   Area1
City1   Area2
Continent1  Country1
Continent2  Country2
Continent3  Country3
Continent4  Country4
Continents  Continent1
Continents  Continent2
Continents  Continent3
Continents  Continent4
Country1    State1
Country2    State2
Country3    State3
Earth   Continents
State1  City1
State1  City1.1
State2  City2
```

My goal is to find all the "descendants" and "ancestors" of given member.

Here is what I have coded do far:

```
import sys, re

with open("input.txt", "r") as my_in:
    collections={}
    for line in my_in:
        parent, child=line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
        collections.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)

print (collections)
'''
{'Continent4': ['Country4'], 'Continent2': ['Country2'], 
'Continents': ['Continent1', 'Continent2', 'Continent3', 'Continent4'], 
'Continent1': ['Country1'], 'Country2': ['State2'], 
'Country3': ['State3'], 'State1': ['City1', 'City1.1'], 
'Country1': ['State1'], 'State2': ['City2'], 
'Earth': ['Continents'], 'City1': ['Area1', 'Area2'], 'Continent3': ['Country3']}
'''

def find_descendants(parent, collections):
descendants = []
for descendant in collections[parent]:
    if descendant in collections:
        descendants = descendants + find_descendants(descendant, collections)
    else:
        descendants.append(descendant)
return descendants

# Get descendants of "Continent1":
lis=find_descendants("Continent1", collections)
print (lis) # It shows ['Area1', 'Area2', 'City1.1']
# Actually it should show ['Country1', 'State1', 'City1', 'Area1', 'Area2',   'City1.1']

def find_ancestors(child, collections):
    # pseudo code
    # link child to its parent and parent to its parent until no more parents are found
    pass

# lis=find_ancestors("City1.1", collections)
# should show ['Earth', 'Continents', 'Continent1', 'Country1', 'State1']
```

The function find_descendants is not working as expected. And as far as find_ancestors function is concerned, although I know the pseudo code, I am not able to express it in Python.

Please help.

Comment: You forget to append `descendant` to `decendants` in your `if descendant in collections:` case

Comment: Thanks R. Saban. I have made that change and function find_descendants looks to be working. But still I am not able to put find_ancestors function to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, you forget to append your descendant before looking 
 deeper in your collection. This works:

```
def find_descendants(parent, collections):
    descendants = []
    for descendant in collections[parent]:
        descendants.append(descendant)
        if descendant in collections:
            descendants = descendants + find_descendants(descendant, collections)
    return descendants
```

For ancestors, just build an other `collections`, say `ancestors_collection`, that stores the reverse relation descendant/ancestor. The function to find ancestors should then be exactly the same as find_descendants, which you can rename accordingly.

EDIT:

> Here a complete working code, I use `relative` to refer to ancestor or descendant:

```
import sys, re

with open("input.txt", "r") as my_in:
    descendants={}
    ancestors={}
    for line in my_in:
        parent, child=line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
        descendants.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
        ancestors.setdefault(child, []).append(parent)

def get_relatives(element, collection):
    relatives = []
    for relative in collection[element]:
        relatives.append(relative)
        if relative in collection:
            relatives = relatives + get_relatives(relative, collection)
    return relatives

# Get descendants of "Continent1":
lis=get_relatives("Continent1", descendants)
print (lis)
# shows ['Country1', 'State1', 'City1', 'Area1', 'Area2',   'City1.1']

lis=get_relatives("City1.1", ancestors)
print (lis)
# shows ['Earth', 'Continents', 'Continent1', 'Country1', 'State1']
```

Comment: Great catch. Thanks. This is working. But I am still stuck with find_ancestors function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler solution that uses `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx

coll = nx.DiGraph()
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        ancestor, descendant = line.split("\t")
        coll.add_edge(ancestor, descendant)

print(nx.descendants(coll, "Continent1"))
# {'Area2', 'City1.1', 'Area1', 'City1', 'State1', 'Country1'}

print(nx.ancestors(coll, "City1.1"))
# {'Earth', 'Continent1', 'State1', 'Continents', 'Country1'}
```

Both functions return a set so the ancestors and descendants are not ordered.